# What is the recommended constructor for Javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, constructor

What is the recommended constructor for JavaScript objects?

**Constructor 1**

```
var myObject = new Object();
myObject.name = "Jim"
myObject.age = 24;
```

**Constructor 2**

```
var myObject = {}
myObject.name = "Jim"
myObject.age = 24
```

**Constructor 3**

```
var myObject = {
name: 'Jim',
age: 24
}
```

Comment: I believe this question is opinion-based, nothing else.

Comment: However, to initialize a constructor, I use method 3. If I want to change something on the road, obviously I use the second method.

Comment: You missed one - if you're building reusable objects: `function myObject(name, age) { this.name = name; this.age = age; } var obj = new myObject("Jim", 24);` This is what I think of when you're talking about a JavaScript Constructor

Comment: What do *you* think is the best way and why?

Comment: Other than the call for the constructor for the `Object`, none of these even use constructors. A constructor is a method call for an object when it's created, then called when you use `new myObject(...)`

Comment: The link provided at the top of this is exactly what I wanted, sorry for the duplicate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the **Constructor 2 or 3** (whatever you want) but **never use Constructor 1** (is a bad practice):

The advantages of object literals over using the respective constructor are:

- Shorter and more readable.
- Safer: literals will still work when the Object constructors
  have been overridden.
- Possibly faster, though it's unlikely to be a major consideration.

**[Update]**

Try always use constructor 3 because is more performant but take in mind that you can use the Constructor 2 approach if you later need to append properties to your object.

Comment: The problem with number 2 is that you are performing a bunch of assignments. Not so bad when it's just two properties, but a potentially huge hit on bigger objects. Method 3 is a single operation. I found this out the hard way when I was 12 and thought it was a good idea to build an entire database in JavaScript by doing `data[123].name.english = "Abc"; data[123].name.french = "Merde";` over and over and over XD

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You are right, what I try to explain is that sometime could be useful if you need to append new properties to your object. Thanks for the contribution.